# Use setState or setProps is more efficient for Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS (by facebook) and I have the option of calling `setState` or `setProps`, but don't know which is more efficient performance-wise.

(Don't take my code on face value. This is just a simplification. My main concern is knowing which of `setProps` or `setState` is faster.)

For setProps I have:

```
function XHRcallback(data) {
  React.renderComponent(MainApp, $("container")).setProps(data);
}
```

For setState I have:

```
var updateAll;

function XHRcallback(data) {
  updateAll(data);
}

var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {

    updateAll = function(data) {
      this.setState(data);
    }.bind(this);

  },

  render: function() {
    //stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

State and props are equally efficient in React; they're used for different things. Think of `props` as inputs to your component, and `state` as internal, private variables.

See [Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html) for a discussion of state vs. props.

Comment: But `setProps` I have to call it at the root. With `setState` I can call it closer to the element being manipulated. So should that be faster?

Comment: You shouldn't be deciding whether to use state or props based on performance. React is fast in both cases. The blog post I linked explains when to use props and when to use state.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. I've read it before but I still can't figure out whether I should be calling `setState` on the element closest to the mode being manipulated, or if I should be calling `setProps` on the root node which means the whole app will need to be rendered all over again. I know that `render` is fast but I still don't like the idea that a whole virtual DOM for the root needs to be generated rather than just generating the virtual DOM for one part of the page.

Comment: I found out `setState` is faster than `setProps` by 23% by the testcase on jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/reactjs-setstate-vs-setprops

Comment: @Anusser why aren't you using `component.setState` like `component.setProps`? this 23% diff should vanish if you use shouldComponentUpdate