# Should I filter my data before calling setProps on Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it faster if I filter my data before calling `setProps` (or `setState`) for Reactjs?

```
var component = React.renderComponent(
  <MainApp />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);

var data = {
  name: "p",
  list: [
    {id:1, name:""},
    {id:2, name:""},
    {id:3, name:""},
    //...
  ]
}
component.setProps(data);
data.name = "w";
```

Now I want to update the "p" to the "w". Is it more efficient/faster if I do this:

```
component.setProps(data);
```

Or this:

```
component.setProps({name: "w"});
```

The latter one doesn't need me to put the whole data object in it again, but then I have to do my own filtering.

If I put in the whole object again with only 1 thing changed, does Reactjs need to process the whole object in `setProps/setState` which slows it down, or will it need to process everything anyway inside `render` so it makes no difference?

---

Edit 1 hour later:

I didn't get a satisfactorily technical answer on which is faster.

Rather than get to the bottom of it, I just did a quick jsPerf testcase to see which is faster and simply accept it as a statistical truth rather than a technological truth.

http://jsperf.com/reactjs-setprops-big-or-setprops-small

The surprising thing is that giving it a large object is faster by a negligible amount. (I thought it would be slower.) I suppose internally ReactJS has to process the whole object anyways regardless of whether my input was small or big. It isn't able to skip over processing the large object (that wasn't modified), so there is no time savings in not passing it the large object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing only the key you need to update is faster by a microscopic amount, but you should pass in whatever's most convenient -- doing your own filtering will cancel out any time advantage that you might gain from passing fewer keys.

Like I said in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980421/49485), these small changes won't make a large enough difference to worry about. Do whatever's easiest, then only if your app is slow, look at adding [`shouldComponentUpdate` methods](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to reduce unnecessary updates.

Comment: Say I am writing an RSS reader. If a person clicks on a message and I load that message, if I call `setProps` with all the JSON, then everything will been to be `render`ed again including the folders list, the list of feeds (thousands!) and the currently opened feed.

Comment: Anusser: To prevent that, you can write a shouldComponentUpdate method *without* restructuring your app at all. This is extremely easy if you're using immutable data, and pretty easy regardless.

Comment: But that sounds counterproductive. That means in my app I have to modify `shouldComponentUpdate` for all other components except my SingleMessage component. That doesn't sound like how React is supposed to be used and sounds like it will result in spaghetti code. In other words I write spaghetti code or React apps are designed to render the whole application everytime 1 little thing changes. Sounds like bad design to me.

Comment: Anusser: I think you will find that React is plenty fast. *IF* your components are too slow, you can try to speed them up later without restructuring your app.

Comment: Is that the _preferred_ way of using React? i.e. render everything every time? I'm asking because this is different from how I program using components in other languages. It is frowned upon to cause a full re-render unless if the framework specifically encourages you to do a full re-render.

Comment: The *preferred* way of using React is to structure your components in a way that makes sense, which makes your app logic much clearer so that you don't need to always worry about exactly which components need updates -- React's diff algorithm will take care of it for you. It's very common to rerender an entire page and you shouldn't try to avoid it.